# name inside bubble in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I make this go away?  I don't know how it got there.  Deleting the row does no good.

[image]

Thanks in advance, for all help.

Comment: What excel version?

Comment: This looks like where another collaborator's currently editing.  If there's only you, you might have multiple instances of the file open.

Comment: I agree with Christopher Hostage, if the Excel file under Share, you'll see the names of who else is also editing the file. If needed, For more information, you could refer to: [How to share Excel file for multiple users and co-author a shared workbook](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/08/02/excel-shared-workbook-share-file-multiple-users/).